# Entity framework - login failed for user 'test'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to develop an MVC app on my local computer and I have huge troubles opening a connection to my database.

**At the same time, I am able to run SQL scripts and they work just fine.**

Whenever a line like this is hit:

```
AsTuLusEntities entity = new AsTuLusEntities();
```

I get the following error:

```
Login failed for user 'test'.
```

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, SQL Server Configuration Manager, but I don't know what's not working and what is wrong.

In SQL Server Management Studio, I have created a user named 'test', server roles sysadmin, securables set on my server with `Connect to SQL` granted. The server is installed on my local machine.

What do I need to do to make this work with Visual Studio?

**EDIT**

Here are my connection strings:

```
<add name="AstulusEntities_ADO" connectionString="data source=192.168.1.143\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=AsTuLus;user id=test;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="AsTuLusEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Database.AsTuLusEntity.csdl|res://*/Models.Database.AsTuLusEntity.ssdl|res://*/Models.Database.AsTuLusEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.1.143\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=AsTuLus;persist security info=True;user id=test;password=***;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: could you post your connection string?

Comment: show your authentication code

Comment: Oh, yes, one minute please!

Comment: There, it is done, sorry about that.

Comment: Why do you need 2 connection strings?

Comment: If you change the connection string to use Integrated Security, does that work?

Comment: @NickeManarin Because in applications that I developped earlier I need to make the ADO connection string for authentification purpose. I am using Web Security.

Comment: @MattyM Well I'd like to do that! How?

Comment: @hsim In your connection string, instead of specifying a username and password, do this: Integrated Security=true. Obviously, you'll only do this on your local machine.